# c++ / sqlite3: Crashes on INSERT Operation with value>8characters

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have a simple sqlite INSERT operation on c++:
My functions reads lines from a text file and generates a SQL command string.

```
[...]
sqlQry = "INSERT into content (\"title\") VALUES (\"" + line + "\")";
cout << sqlQry.c_str() << endl;

rc = sqlite3_exec(db, sqlQry.c_str(), callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
cout << "RC: " << rc << endl;

if( rc!=SQLITE_OK ){
  fprintf(stderr, "SQL error: %s\n", zErrMsg);
  sqlite3_free(zErrMsg);
}
```

I filled the text file with dummy content, a "test" word with one additional char in each line.
My program returns sqlite error code 21, if the the is bigger than 7 characters.
My program crashes, if the string is bigger than  9 characters.

Command line output:

```
INSERT into content ("title") VALUES ("test")
RC: 0
testt
INSERT into content ("title") VALUES ("testt")
RC: 0
testte
INSERT into content ("title") VALUES ("testte")
RC: 0
testtes
INSERT into content ("title") VALUES ("testtes")
RC: 0
testtest
INSERT into content ("title") VALUES ("testtest") // sqlite3_exec returns 21
RC: 21
SQL error: (null)
testtestt
INSERT into content ("title") VALUES ("testtestt")  // sqlite3_exec returns 21
RC: 21
SQL error: (null)
testtesttt
INSERT into content ("title") VALUES ("testtesttt") // program crashes on sqlite3SafetyCheckOk
// The debugger is pointing on line 22814 - (magic = db->magic)
```

The Result Code 21 is defined as follow:

```
#define SQLITE_MISUSE      21   /* Library used incorrectly */
```

I am a beginner on sqlite3 and have been trying to solve this error for a few hours.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should show your schema. Is there a restriction to the value width? E.g. `varchar(7)`? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query